# Converting Java.util date to XML date without time zone

Tags: java

I'm using below code to convert java util date to XML gregorian calendar date, but the conversion is somehow adding the time zone to the date.

```
GregorianCalendar gregorianCalendar = new GregorianCalendar();
gregorianCalendar.setTimeInMillis(dte.getTime());
XMLGregorianCalendar xmlGrogerianCalendar = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(gregorianCalendar);
return xmlGrogerianCalendar;
```

I don't want the time zone to be the part of the date. Can any one point out how can i achieve this?

Comment: Your comment on one of the answers below appears to contradict what you're saying in the question. Do you want the timezone suffix or not? Or are you saying you want UTC (GMT / Zulu time)?

Answer (score 14):

You can change the timezone so it is undefined. Undefined fields (within reason) won't be included in the output.

```
XMLGregorianCalendar xmlGregorianCalendar = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(gregorianCalendar);
xmlGregorianCalendar.setTimezone( DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED );
```

Comment: How can i get the month as Jan/feb etc instaead of numbers ?

Comment: You're now asking a completely different different question. I would suggest you start a new StackOverflow question and be specific about the format you actually need the date in.

Answer (score 2):

You could try setting set the fields individually

```
GregorianCalendar gregorianCalendar = new GregorianCalendar();
gregorianCalendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());

try {
    XMLGregorianCalendar xmlGrogerianCalendar = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar();
    xmlGrogerianCalendar.setYear(gregorianCalendar.get(GregorianCalendar.YEAR));
    xmlGrogerianCalendar.setMonth(gregorianCalendar.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH));
    xmlGrogerianCalendar.setDay(gregorianCalendar.get(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    xmlGrogerianCalendar.setHour(gregorianCalendar.get(GregorianCalendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
    xmlGrogerianCalendar.setMinute(gregorianCalendar.get(GregorianCalendar.MINUTE));
    xmlGrogerianCalendar.setSecond(gregorianCalendar.get(GregorianCalendar.SECOND));

    System.out.println(xmlGrogerianCalendar.toXMLFormat() );

} catch (DatatypeConfigurationException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I need to pass the value to the soap webservice and if try to use the       xmlGrogerianCalendar.setTimezone( DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED ); i 'm unable to send the request ,it fails..when i set manually each field indiviadually ,t takes default time zone and again the request fails .Is there any other way ?

Comment: I'd say that the problem would be with the soap webservice, not with construction of the object. You need to look at the error that the WS is producing, and see if you try setting a specific TZ that it will accept? I assume that it does not like an undefined TZ.

Answer (score 0):

Beware java.util.Calendar use 0-based month numbering, while XMLGregorianCalendar 1-based.

```
GregorianCalendar gregorianCalendar = new GregorianCalendar();
gregorianCalendar.setTimeInMillis(new Date().getTime());
XMLGregorianCalendar xmlGregorianCalendar = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar();
xmlGregorianCalendar.setYear(gregorianCalendar.get(GregorianCalendar.YEAR));
xmlGregorianCalendar.setMonth(gregorianCalendar.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH) + 1);
xmlGregorianCalendar.setDay(gregorianCalendar.get(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
System.out.println(xmlGregorianCalendar);
```

> 2021-08-04